# Problemas para lanzar página dentro de onclick, JS

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un código, cuando me valida todo no llega a lanzar la página, ¿Por qué? Dejo el código, a ver qué se les ocurre. Gracias.

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var envia;
    var email;
    var contrasena;

    envia = document.getElementById('envia');
    email = document.getElementById('email');
    contrasena = document.getElementById('contrasena');

    envia.onclick = function(){

        var valor1 = email.value;
        var valor2 = contrasena.value;

            if(valor1=="" || valor2=="") {
                alert("Error: los campos email o contraseña estan vacios.");
            }
            else{
                alert("acceso Correcto"); 
                location.href="direccion.html";
            }
    }
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Copiando el código a JSFiddle funciona perfectamente y sin problemas. ¿Qué es lo que te falla exactamente?¿Ves algún error en la consola de JS?

Comment: No veo ningún problema en este código. Añade el resto del código de tu página para ver si hay algún problema en eso. Asegúrate de que se esté ejecutando este código luego de que sea cargado el DOM.

Comment: Por casualidad el elemento con "id=envia" no será un botón de envío de formulario? Podrías poner el código HTML para poder ayudarte de manera más precisa?

Comment: ok, copiare el codigo aqui completo, todo funciona me valida pero no lanza la pagina, el id="envia" es un boton que envia la contraseña e email. les dejo el codigo:

Answer (score 1):

Se que no has publicado tu `html` donde tienes el `form` pero supongo que el problema esta en el `button` que envía el `form`.

si estas usando el `<button type="submit">Enviar</button>` o lo que sería igual`<button>Enviar</button>` entonces no te va a funcionar porque estas usando el evento `onclick` sobre el `button` que a su vez esta ejecutando el evento `onsubmit` y te esta re-direccionando antes de aplicar tu re-dirección.

Tu `form` debería ser por ejemplo:

```
<form>
    <input type="email" id="email" value="email" placeholder="user">
    <input type="password" id="contrasena" value="pass" placeholder="pass">
    <button type="button" id="envia">Envia</button>
</form>
```

Entonces en el `button` de tipo `button` puedes usar el evento `onclick` sin que se envíe el `form` antes.

Aqui te pongo un ejemplo en vivo:

http://embed.plnkr.co/FWwv2R/

Comment: carlos meneses, no e podido publicar el html, no se donde, como puedo usar la pagina que usaste, para el codigo, para enviarlo ahi.....miral a lineaa del boton, <button id="envia" class="botonRojo">Continuar &gt;</button>

Comment: gracias carlos, me di cuenta que en la linea button le hacia falta el type="button", no se si lo borre o algo, Gracias Millll, Gracias a todos

Answer (score 0):

Intenta remplazando el `location.href="direccion.html";`
 por `window.location = "direaccion.html"`

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar por qué la referencia a `window` podría afectar el comportamiento que está observando el autor o cómo contribuiría a solucionar el problema? Así como está expresado pareciera más un comentario para que pruebe otra opción sin tener claro por qué o qué estaría sucediendo, y no una respuesta a la pregunta.

Comment: Aunque añadir `window` no creo que te solucione el problema suele ser una buena practica utilizar `window` ya que nos recuerda que se trata de una variable global.

Comment: sip hice eso y no funciono, no se que pasa....

Comment: Sin duda @oscarsolis, es una buena práctica muy recomendable. Más aún si es completo, como `window.location.href`. Pero quizás sería mejor poner esto como comentario en la pregunta, aclarando que es una buena práctica que debería utilizar (y que no resuelve el problema).

Answer (score 0):

//Ya terminado el codigo queda así:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var envia;
    var email;
    var contrasena;

    envia = document.getElementById('envia');
    email = document.getElementById('email');
    contrasena = document.getElementById('contrasena');

    envia.onclick = function(){

        var valor1 = email.value;
        var valor2 = contrasena.value;

           if(valor1!=""&&valor2!=""){
            location.href="direccion.html";
            return false;
          }else{
            alert("debes llenar los 2 campos");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Y que fue que no le funcionó al OP? Eso era parte de la pregunta.